# adjacency matrix implementation for a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a positive integer n, generate a simple directed
graph with n vertices by producing an adjacency matrix
for the graph so that all simple directed graphs with n
vertices are equally likely to be generated.

what does "all simple directed graphs with n
vertices are equally likely to be generated" mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the question is very badly phrased. If you know the answer it is obvious, if you don't, you cannot understand the question. Essentially, the question asks for the following:

1) You are looking for some recipe to generate directed graphs with a prescribed number of vertices/nodes. The way in which you are supposed to specify the graph is a square matrix, the adjacency matrix `A`, where `A[i,j] = 1` signifies that the is a connection from vertex/node `i` to `j`.

2) This recipe should include some initialisation step that involves random numbers such that probability that you end up with any specific graph (for example the fully connected graph) is the same for **all** possible graphs of size n.